# Expected value of betting gains (de Finetti)/ Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Reading de Finetti's "Foresight", there is an issue I would like to clarify:

We have $n$ mutually exclusive events, $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$, that we believe to occur with probability $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ respectively. Now we want to bet on those events, so if for example $E_1$ materialized and the others not, we would make a gain of $(1-p_1)S_1 - p_2S_2 - \dots -p_nS : = G_1$, that is we wager $p_1S_1 + p_2S_2+ \dots + p_nS_n$ to win either $S_1, S_2$, or $S_n$.

This gives a system of linear equations, with the determinant of the coefficient matrix necessarily equal to zero. Otherwise, we could construct a Dutch Book.

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
1-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 &\dots & -p_n \\
-p_1 & 1-p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & p_n \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & 1-p_n
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i = 0
$$

De Finetti now claims that, if the determinant is equal to $0$, the expected value of the gains is equal to $0$, or $\sum_{i=1}^n p_iG_i = 0$. I verified the result for the first three dimensions, but have failed to generalize it so far.

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this can be done by simplifying the double summation, it might be more revealing to do the algebra with matrix notation.

Let $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n)^\prime$, $S=(S_1,S_,\ldots, S_n)^\prime$, and $G=(G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_n)^\prime$ represent the information as column vectors. Write $\mathbf{1}=(1,1,\ldots, 1)^\prime$ and let $\mathbb{I}_n$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

We know

$$p^\prime \mathbf{1}=1,$$

we are given

$$G = (\mathbb{I}_n - \mathbf{1}p^\prime)S,$$

and wish to compute the number

$$p^\prime G.$$

Substituting the foregoing into this expression gives

$$p^\prime G = p^\prime(\mathbb{I}_n - \mathbf{1}p^\prime)S = p^\prime S - (p^\prime \mathbf{1}) (p^\prime S) = p^\prime S - (1)(p^\prime S) = 0,$$

*QED*.

Comment: Once again, I am indebted to you, @whuber. Thank you very much indeed! Your skill and expertise is really inspiring, I hope that with the years I shall come somewhat closer to your level of knowledge!

Comment: I have long been grateful for having had the opportunity, very early in my career, of taking a challenging and rigorous course in linear algebra.  Such courses are difficult to find, but nevertheless I would warmly recommend the experience for anyone wishing to work in a quantitative field.

Comment: Yes, I see the necessity as well. Despite receiving the equivalent of As in my LinAlg and Linear Models classes, I picked up "Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective" and read in it, whenever I have some spare time. Would you have further recommendations?

Comment: There must be thousands of current linear algebra texts, and the one I used is now very old (but not outmoded!), so I'm in no position to make recommendations. There is an ongoing stream of reviews in *The American Statistician* that over the years has covered such textbooks from a statistical perspective, so that might be a good place to do some research.